# Pandas dataFrame creation

Tags: python, pandas

i want to create a pandas data frame with this following  dictionary

```
     a ={('p','l',2):3,('p','l',3):4,('p','l1',5):4,('p','l',5):4,
      ('p','l',6):2,('p','l2',6):4,('p','l1',2):5}

              m n o p
            o p l 2 3
            1 p l 3 4
            2 p l1 5 4
            3 p l 6 2
```

i wrote the following logic
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['m','n','o','p']) 
but it is not working , can you please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(a.keys()), columns=list('mno'))
df['p'] = list(a.values())

df

   m   n  o  p
0  p  l2  6  4
1  p   l  6  2
2  p   l  3  4
3  p   l  5  4
4  p  l1  2  5
5  p  l1  5  4
6  p   l  2  3
```

---

(*Edit*) Getting back a dict post `groupby`: if you want the result for just `p`, then call `mean` on `p` followed by `to_dict` -

```
df.groupby(['m', 'n']).p.mean().to_dict()
{('p', 'l'): 3.25, ('p', 'l1'): 4.5, ('p', 'l2'): 4.0}
```

Comment: Nice one bro:-)

Comment: @Wen Thanks for the support as always! Hope to see some answers from you too :)

Comment: It is hard for me to think out side the box from yours and Jez's :-)

Comment: hii bro  how can i convert it back to my dict after performing group by columns m and n and performing average

Comment: @maniramreddy You mean if there are only 2 elements in each key?

Comment: thanks a lot ,but i do not need the key like 'o' and 'p',i just want {('p', 'l'): 3.25, ('p', 'l1'): 4.5, ('p', 'l2'): 4.0}}

Comment: finally find a new way .. :-)

Comment: @maniramreddy If keys O and P are missing, then what will the dictionary know to show?

Comment: HII BRO I WANT TO GROUP BY AND PERFORM ADDITION AND DIVIDE IT WITH CERTAIN NUMBER AND THEN CONVERT TO DICTIONARY CAN YOU HELP ME ON IT

Comment: @maniramreddy You do realise you can ask a new question, right? Please open a new question with your data and expected output, and I'll help.

Answer (score 2):

Bu using numpy

```
pd.DataFrame(np.append(np.array(list(a.keys())),np.array(list(a.values()))[:,None],1),columns=list('abcd'))
Out[1151]: 
   a   b  c  d
0  p   l  2  3
1  p   l  3  4
2  p  l1  5  4
3  p   l  5  4
4  p   l  6  2
5  p  l2  6  4
6  p  l1  2  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Series` constructor with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.Series(a).reset_index()
df.columns=['m','n','o','p']
print (df)
   m   n  o  p
0  p   l  2  3
1  p   l  3  4
2  p   l  5  4
3  p   l  6  2
4  p  l1  2  5
5  p  l1  5  4
6  p  l2  6  4
```

Or use `list comprehension` first for nested `list`s:

```
a = [list(k) + [v] for k,v in a.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['m','n','o','p']) 
print (df)
   m   n  o  p
0  p   l  2  3
1  p   l  5  4
2  p  l2  6  4
3  p  l1  2  5
4  p   l  3  4
5  p   l  6  2
6  p  l1  5  4
```

Comment: I like both of the solutions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through `pd.MultiIndex` and with Pandas 0.21.0 you can use `set_axis`:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(a.keys())
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data=list(a.values()), index=idx).reset_index()\
           .set_axis(['m','n','o','p'], axis=1, inplace=False)
df_out
```

Output:

```
   m   n  o  p
0  p   l  2  3
1  p  l1  2  5
2  p   l  6  2
3  p  l2  6  4
4  p   l  3  4
5  p  l1  5  4
6  p   l  5  4
```